# Data Binding result between textarea or radio buttons + angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hello this doubt arises me,

I have a textarea to enter text and also a radio button to select an option.

How could show the following: If you type something in the textarea, which show only the text entered, if you choose an option from the radio button, you delete the contents of the textarea and display the selected radio button option.

Jsbin basic example: http://jsbin.com/pejufu/8/edit?html,js,output

Thanks for the help!

Comment: do you just want a final result of showing testarea or radio based on your logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ng-change` to set the final result based on your logic:

**html**:

```
<textarea ng-model="text.text1" ng-change="setResult()" placeholder="Write here" style="min-width: 355px"></textarea>

<label ng-repeat="name in names" for="{{name}}">
  {{name}}
  <input type="radio" ng-model="my.favorite" ng-change="setResult()" ng-value="name" id="{{name}}" name="favorite">
</label>

<p>
  Result or textarea or radio is: {{my.result}}
</p>
```

**js**:

```
$scope.my = { favorite: '', result: '' };

$scope.checkResult = function () {
    $scope.my.result = $scope.text.text1 ? $scope.text.text1 : $scope.my.favorite;
};
```